# Word-Break & Display:Inline Don't Work

Tags: html, css

This `Lorem ipsum` text goes out of the div and whatever I have tried, I couldn't make it fit. It doesn't get line-break either.

By the way, I am using chrome.

How can I achieve this auto line breaking?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="word-break: break-all; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden ">
    <div> Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsumLorem ipsum lorem ipsumLorem ipsum lorem ipsumLorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am placing it in a Bootstrap Dropdown as a row.

Edit: `line-break: strict;` doesn't work either. Neither do `text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 150px; white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Edited it into simple format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused because it was Bootstrap Dropdown:

Here is the solution:
`style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal;"`